# jQuery - Display a custom Modal

Tags: jquery

I would like to display a custom Modal dialogue.  I know about the libraries that are available that allow customization via StyleSheets. Can I create my own `<div>` and have it popup like a dialogue without adding all that extra fluff?

Comment: this might help you http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-completely-reusable-jquery-modal-window/ http://deseloper.org/read/2008/04/a-simple-modal/

Comment: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: Its takes a little getting used to, but this is the right idea.  Its basic and somewhat easy to edit.  At least with direct CSS manipulation.  Be sure **not** to include the demo.css file in your real project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a link to jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)

The way that I make a modal dialog is create my dialog inside div tags with style="display:none;" so it won't appear until I choose to. The example on jquery UI's page goes:

```
$( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            height: 140,
            modal: true
});
```